# Stock_quote version 2.0.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm currently having issues with gem stock_quote version 2.0.0. I have installed the gem using "bundle install" and included the necessary code snippet as below. However,  When I ran the code from the browser using "localhost:3000" on chrome, the server terminates suddenly with the following error.

> C:/tools/ruby25/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98
>   Processing by HomeController#index as HTML  Rendering
>   home/index.html.erb within layouts/application Segmentation fault

The browser gives this error: "This site can't be reached. ERR_CONNECTION RESET."

Below is my code.

Segment code inside the gemFile

```
ruby '2.5.1'
# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.2.0'
gem 'mysql2', '>= 0.4.4', '< 0.6.0'
gem 'puma', '~> 3.11'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'autoprefixer-rails'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.7'
gem 'bootstrap', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'stock_quote', '~> 2.0.0'
home_controller.rb

class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @stock = StockQuote::Stock.quote("goog")
  end
  def about
  end
end
```

Index.html.erb

```
<h1>STOCKER</h1>
<p>This is from Stocker page!</p>
```

I'd appreciate your help on the above.

Thanks.

Comment: heya - there's not enough info here for us to figure out what the problem is. Sounds like there might plausibly be a bug in the gem... have you looked at the issue-list for the gem to see if it's listed there?

Comment: Can you try to comment the link `@stock = ...` and check, did it work then ?

Comment: It works me when I comment out the @stock = .... It even works when used from rails console. But it doesn't work from the app.